# Need vector slices to live longer

Tags: vector, rust, lifetime

Is there any way to get the slices of this vector to last long enough so that I can use them in this kind of circular structure?

```
fn populate_chain(file_path: &str) -> HashMap<String, HashSet<&String>> {
    println!("loading...");
    let time = util::StopWatch::new();
    let mut words = HashMap::new();
    {
        let f = |mut x: Vec<String>| {
            let word = x.pop().unwrap();
            words.insert(word, HashSet::new());
        };
        Csv::process_rows(f, file_path, "\t");
    }

    let col: Vec<(String, HashSet<&String>)> = words.clone().into_iter().collect();
    let m: usize = col.len() - 1;
    for i in 0..m {
        let ref k: String = col[i].0;
        for j in i..m {
            let ref nk: String = col[j].0;
            if check_link(k, nk) {
                words.get_mut(k).unwrap().insert(nk);
                words.get_mut(nk).unwrap().insert(k);
            }
        }
    }

    time.print_time();
    words
}
```

I'm using the double for loops to chain words together which are related so that they can be quickly looked up later.

Here are the compiler errors...

```
error: `col` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:28:29
   |
28 |         let ref k: String = col[i].0;
   |                             ^^^ does not live long enough
...
40 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 13:72...
  --> src/main.rs:13:73
   |
13 | fn populate_chain(file_path: &str) -> HashMap<String, HashSet<& String>>{
   |                                                                         ^

error: `col` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:30:34
   |
30 |             let ref nk: String = col[j].0;
   |                                  ^^^ does not live long enough
...
40 | }
   | - borrowed value only lives until here
   |
note: borrowed value must be valid for the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the block at 13:72...
  --> src/main.rs:13:73
   |
13 | fn populate_chain(file_path: &str) -> HashMap<String, HashSet<& String>>{
   |
```

Comment: I suggest you use a library like [`petgraph`](https://docs.rs/petgraph/0.4.3/petgraph/) to construct a graph structure.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Being a part of this community involves some basic guidelines, such as providing a [MCVE] when asking a question. This question does not currently provide the proper imports, it omits the declaration of `util`, and it doesn't define `Csv`. It also had all sorts of "junk" in the code. Please provide a **minimal** reproduction as well. I doubt you need a "`StopWatch`" to show us the problem. Also, there are [**297 existing questions with this error**](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Brust%5D+is%3Aq+does+not+live+long+enough). Please tell us how this is different.

Answer (score 0):

I can tell you from your function signature that you're going to have big problems trying to write this function, at least if you want it to contain non-empty `HashSet`s in the result.

```
fn populate_chain(file_path: &str) -> HashMap<String, HashSet<&String>>
```

This function signature has references in it; they have elided lifetimes. If you make the inferred lifetimes explicit, it would look like this:

```
fn populate_chain<'a>(file_path: &'a str) -> HashMap<String, HashSet<&'a String>>
```

In other words: This function claims that, given some string slice with lifetime `'a`, it will give back a collection that holds `String` objects with lifetime `'a`.

But you have no means for allocating such `String` objects within your code. :(

So, you're stuck; no matter what you put into that function body, you're not going to be able to supply an implementation that returns a non-trivial result with respect to the `HashSet`s.

However, all is not lost. You could, for example, revise your function so that it also takes as an additional parameter a reference to a `TypedArena` with an appropriate lifetime, and then allocate the strings there. Another (simpler) option would be to use `HashSet<String>` instead of `HashSet<&String>`...